# No me muestra el array hasta que utilizo una pipe Angular

Tags: ajax, array, angular

Tengo un problema y es que utilizando el subscribe de Ajax, no me muestra el array de pokemons hasta que no utilizo una pipe. Es decir que la aplicación cuando la inicio me sale en blanco, y solo muestra información cuando utilizo la pipe.

Este es el component

```
verpokes:any = null;
verpok:any = null;
poke:Pokaimons[] =[];

constructor(mostra: HtajaxService) {  
this.poke = [];

mostra.pokemons().subscribe(Response => {
  this.verpokes= Response;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.verpokes.results.length; i++) {
    mostra.pokemon(i).subscribe(Response => {
      this.verpok = Response;
      this.poke.push(new Pokaimons(this.verpok.name, this.verpok.types[0].type.name, this.verpok.types[1].type.name, this.verpok.weight, this.verpok.height, this.color, this.color2, this.colorpok, this.verpok.stats[0].base_stat, this.verpok.stats[1].base_stat, this.verpok.stats[2].base_stat, this.verpok.stats[5].base_stat, this.verpok.sprites.front_default));
    });
  }
});
}
```

Asi es como llamo al array

```
<div id="pokes{{i}}" *ngFor = "let pokes of poke | tipus: trobatipus | cercar: cercadorPokes | ordena: ordena; index as i" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
```

Esta es la clase de pokemons

```
export class Pokaimons {
nom: string
tipus1: string
tipus2: string
pes: number
altura: number
color: string
color2: string
colorpok: string
vida: string
atac: number
defensa: number
velocitat: number
img: string

constructor(nom:any, tipus1:any, tipus2:any, pes:any, altura:any, color:any, color2:any, colorpok:any, vida:any, atac:any, defensa:any, velocitat:any, img:any){
    this.nom = nom;
    this.tipus1 = tipus1;
    this.tipus2 = tipus2;
    this.pes = pes;
    this.altura = altura;
    this.color = color;
    this.color2 = color2;
    this.colorpok = colorpok;
    this.vida = vida;
    this.atac = atac;
    this.defensa = defensa;
    this.velocitat = velocitat;
    this.img = img;
}
}
```

La llamada de la información me lo hace perfectamente i me recorre el array bien, ningún problema, pero solo muestra cada pokemon si utilizo una pipe.

Comment: Es normal, es una llamada asíncrona: la llamada a console.log se hace antes de obtener la respuesta

Comment: Puedes crear un `<ng-container *ngIf="poke> ...tu contendio...<ng-container>` para mitigar esto y mostrar en cambio una precarga.